# Maintaining the Global Scores of a Game

Tags: ios

I am programming an iPhone game and I want to show to the users the game global scores as DoodleJump or Canabalt do. Programming with iOS, what is the best way to store the global scores information?

Thanks for reading.

EDITED: I am reading about Game Center leaders board and is a good option to do what I want. Anyway, there is another way to do it without using Game Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are other ways. Apps were doing this before Game Center. However ask your self this: "Is it worth my time to roll my own leaders board, or just use game centers?" Usually as a user of an app I hardly care about the top scores. Yes I want them but I'd rather the dev do as little work there as possible and spend the time on making more levels, or other enhancements to the actual game play.

Comment: You are right Jamone. Is better to use Game Center. Thanks for your answer.